# For-loop iteration issue with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, xlsxwriter

I am trying to build for loop with xlsxwriter to write my list row by row. My code block;

```
driver.get("file:///C:/HTML/new.html")

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("test.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("PC list")

header = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/th")
headers = []
for h in header:
    headers.append(h.text)
worksheet.write_row("A1", headers) # writes 1st row without any issue

trs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table//tr")
for tr in trs[1:]:
    row=[td.text for td in tr.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")]
    worksheet.write_row("A2", row) # It overwrites each time
workbook.close()
```

It overwrites each time, hence I only see the last one in Excel;
[image]

But I want to see like this;

[image]

I guess "A2" must be incremented each time but how?

```
worksheet.write_row("A2", row) # It overwrites each time
```

Is it possible in xlsxwriter? Can someone please advice what to do? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update the number of the row you are writing to, like this:

```py
for n, tr in enumerate(trs[1:]):
    row=[td.text for td in tr.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")]
    n_row = 2 + n
    worksheet.write_row(f"A{n_row}", row) # It overwrites each time
```

The function `enumerate` returns two values: a number and the value you are iterating over.
The rest is straightforward I think.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much my friend. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to use the alternate form of `write_row` which takes the row and column.

You can see it [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html)

So something like this:

```py
for row_num, tr in enumerate(trs[1:]):
    row_data=[td.text for td in tr.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")]
    worksheet.write_row(row_num, 0, row_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "worksheet.write_row(row_num, 0, row_data)" overwritten the 1st line row which means "headers = []". Once I changed 0 to 1, sheet turned out to diff style.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the destination row from A2 to A3 then A4 and so on as you iterate and write the rows to the file... in your code update your `for` loop a little bit:

```
for n, tr in enumerate(trs[1:]):
    row=[td.text for td in tr.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")]
    worksheet.write_row("A{}".format(2+n), row)
```